# floating div, when is larger than windows height than apply bottom margin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have floating div which content is dynamically populated using js function.
I'm using following code to make this div float

```
// Stick the #nav to the top of the window
    var nav = $('#right-div');
    var navHomeY = nav.offset().top;
    var isFixed = false;
    var $w = $(window);
    $w.scroll(function() {
        var scrollTop = $w.scrollTop();
        var shouldBeFixed = scrollTop > navHomeY;
        if (shouldBeFixed && !isFixed) {
            nav.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: 0,
                left: nav.offset().left,
                width: nav.width()
            });
            isFixed = true;
        }
        else if (!shouldBeFixed && isFixed)
        {
            nav.css({
                position: 'static'
            });
            isFixed = false;
        }
    });
});
```

sometimes when enough content items is added this div height is larger than windows and part of div content is not visible at all, it stays bellow page margin.

So I'm thinking on js function where content is generated before adding to floating div to calculate windows height and floating div and simply apply bottom margin to floating div

```
if ($(window).height() < $("#right-div").height()) {
      alert("float div is larger than window");
      $("#right-div").css({bottom:100});            
}
```

on firebug I see this applied bottom margin (100px) but part of div content is still hidden.

Comment: maybe better just set max-height and add scroll(overflow: auto) to this div?

Comment: I do not want to use scroll. Thank though.